# Scann the value of an span and add an counter in another div when the value is 0 or less

Tags: javascript, if-statement

Im trying to scann the value of an span element, by clicking an button. And if the value of the span is 0 the counter in the div is supposed to add one.

Here is a part of the HTML i use:

```
<span id="result"></span>
<button id="calculateBtn">Calculate</button>
<div id="playerlegs"></div>
```

I already tried something out with JS but nothing happens and i don't now why and what could also work.

```
const button = document.querySelector("#calculateBtn");
const spanElement = document.querySelector("#result");
const displayElement = document.querySelector("#playerlegs");

let count = 0;

button.addEventListener("click", function() {
  const spanValue = parseInt(spanElement.textContent, 10);

  if (spanValue === 0) {
    count++;
    displayElement.innerHTML = count;
  } else if (spanValue < 0) {
    displayElement.innerHTML = "Negative number";
  }
});
```

Comment: What's the value of `spanValue` when you click the button?

Comment: If there is no text content in the span, spanValue will be parseInt("", 10), which results in NaN, and neither of those if statements will be true.

Comment: @mykaf the value of the span, is the sum of the values from three input fields, so the span value chances every time the sum of the input fields chances. I didn't say this in the Question because I thought it wouldn't chance anything.